# Generating The Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

This is related to an ongoing event. It involves generating the following series :
http://oeis.org/A008826

The generating Function as given in the above link is :

```
A(n,x) = Sum{ Stirling2(n,k) * A(k,x) * x } for k : 0 to n-1
```

where stirling2(n,k) is : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

I have made a simple loop to calculate the small A[n,k] :

```
for(int k = 0;k<n;k++)
    a(n,x) += stirling(n,k)*a(k,x)*x;
```

where stirling(n,k) is calculated by

```
stirling(n,k) = (stirling(n-1,k)*k)+stirling(n-1,k-1)
```

i have set

```
stirling(0,0) = 1
stirling(i,0) = stirling(0,i) = 0
A(1,i) = 1
```

The values of the Stirling Numbers being generated are correct.
But the values for A(n,x) being generated do not match http://oeis.org/A008826/table

The output I am receiving is :

```
1       1       1       1       1   
1       2       3       4       5   
4       14      30      52      80  
32      198     606     1364    2580    
436     4722    20568   60004   139380
```

Did I get the function wrong ? Why isn't my output matching the one given in the link ? Am I interpreting the GF incorrectly ?

### EDIT

I was finally able to calculate A(n;x) for small as well as large numbers.
My final recurrence relation has come down to :

F(n) = A(n)*B(n) + (nC2 * F(n-1))

Last step to solve the recurrence relation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track; you are just interpreting the `a(n,x)` incorrectly.  The `a(n,x)` are *polynomials* - and the numbers in (`n-1`)st row of the triangular array are the coefficients by `x`, `x^2`, ... , `x^n` in `a(n,x)`.

For instance, the polynomial `a(4,x)` is `x+13x^2+18x^3`, corresponding to the third row (namely `1 13 18`) of the triangular array.

Comment: Understood. It makes a lot more sense now :)